# How to include RxAndroid in project?

Tags: android, rx-java

I'm using Android Studio. How can I include RxAndroid in my project as a subproject? I want to build it from the sourcecode.
What I've tried:
-Include it as a git submodule.
-included it in my projects settings.gradle file, "include ':rxandroid', ':app'"

Then I get: Error:Unable to find module with Gradle path ':rxandroid'.

**Edit**

My folder structure is as follows.

```
Project
-app
-rxandroid
```

**Edit 2**

I changed the folder name from rxandroid to RxAndroid. I also changed the name in the projects settings.gradle, but I still get the same error.

Comment: Do you want to build it during your app build ? 
Can you show your directory structure ? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, I want to build it during app build.

Answer (score 2):

According to http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/user-guide#TOC-Multi-project-setup it should simply work by changing settings.gradle to:

```
include ':app', ':RxAndroid'
```

And it does work for me. My setup is

- Android Studio 0.8.13
- RxAndroid cloned from https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxAndroid
- My project is using com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.12.+

EDIT:

I should mention that I'm still running Gradle 1.12. I created a new blank project in Android Studio, added RxAndroid to settings.gradle, and a build error appeared:

```
Error:Cause: startup failed:
Could not instantiate global transform class org.spockframework.compiler.SpockTransform specified at jar:file:/path/spock-core/0.7-groovy-1.8/3a677d19e8d3acf3bd296c4023356256d55da5a3/spock-core-0.7-groovy-1.8.jar!/META-INF/services/org.codehaus.groovy.transform.ASTTransformation  because of exception org.spockframework.util.IncompatibleGroovyVersionException: The Spock compiler plugin cannot execute because Spock 0.7.0-groovy-1.8 is not compatible with Groovy 2.3.6. For more information, see http://versioninfo.spockframework.org
Spock location: file:/path/spock-core-0.7-groovy-1.8.jar
Groovy location: file:/path/gradle-2.1/lib/groovy-all-2.3.6.jar
```

It seems RxAndroid depends on Spock 0.7-groovy-1.8 which won't work with Groovy 2.3.6 of Gradle 2.1. And the latest com.android.tools.build (0.13.x) requires Gradle 2.1.

So I did the following:

- in the top level build.gradle (not the app one) change the project's dependency on com.android.tools.build back to 0.12.+
- change the Gradle version in gradle-wrapper.properties back to 1.12

Now the project built successfully.

Comment: Yes, I've checked and my folder it's named rxandroid. I'm on a windows box. Which OS are you using?

Comment: @ErikZ MBP running OS X 10.10

Comment: I would really appreciate if you have the opportunity to upload your project so I can test it. :)

Comment: @ErikZ Sorry I can't upload my whole project. However, I created a new blank project and did encounter build issue with RxAndroid. Not sure if it's the same one you met but I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: It's not the same error as I get. Can you upload the new project you made?

Comment: I have the same problem re: Spock location and Groovy location after updating to latest Android Studio Canary channel build (0.9.1). Can't go backwards due to Android Studio requirement of 0.14.0 gradle plugin dependency which again requires latest Gradle.. Any idea?